# Sort a set of elements by their field

Tags: java, enums, comparable

i have a `set` A of objects from the same class, and each of them has an `Enum` field ,which is `comparable`.
how can i sort the set by that field?
i thought about something like:

```
Collections.sort(A, enumField)
```

but of course that `enumField` is not an object to be compared by...

Comment: Please provide some details into what code you have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Collections.sort` does not accept a `Set`. It only accepts `List`s, so first you should convert your set to a list:

```
ArrayList<YourObject> list = new ArrayList<>(yourSet);
```

Then you can call `Collections.sort` with a custom comparator:

```
Collections.sort(list, Comparator.comparing(x -> x.enumField));
// now "list" contains the sorted elements.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Comparator#comparing` in combination with `Stream`

```
Set<T> sorted = set.stream()
                   .sorted(Comparator.comparing(A::getEnumField))
                   .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new))
```

We need to preserve order, that's why collecting to a `LinkedHashSet`. However this will work only if you don't plan to add any additional element to the set. A better alternative is to use  a `TreeSet`

```
Set sorted  = new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparing(A::getEnumField))));
sorted.addAll(set);
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot sort a `Set` with `Collections.sort` as it only consumes a `List<T>`.

instead, you can make your set a `TreeSet` with the provided comparator:

```
Set<A> mySet = new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparing(A::getEnumField));
```

meaning elements will be sorted as you add.

or if you don't have control to change the set that already has elements in it, you can use the stream API, collecting to a `TreeSet` with the aforementioned comparator which then yields a new `TreeSet` with sorted elements.

```
Set<A> sortedSet = mySet.stream()
                     .collect(Collectors.toCollection(() ->
                        new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparing(A::getEnumField))));
```